# What do you call the habit of looking into smartphone while walking?

Tags: expressions, phrase-requests, translation

The habit of looking into and texting on a smartphone is becoming a prevailing social phenomena in Japan these days. We call this habit “歩きスマホ – aruki sumaho – using a smart-phone while walking” in Japanese. It’s a derivative of “歩きタバコ – aruki tabaco – smoking while walking.” Aruki sumaho is really dangerous because you might hit a pedestrian when you are looking into a smartphone while you are walking; similarly, “aruki tabaco” inflicts a burn if the lit cigarette touches the face or hand of a passer-by. Actually, many cases of injuries caused by “aruki sumaho” (such as a fall from a subway platform) were reported. I saw a young man looking into a smartphone while riding a bicycle on the pavement recently. I learned that the similar trends are observed today in many parts of the world on TV.

What do you call “aruki sumaho – looking into a smartphone while walking” and “a walker looking into smart phone” in brief English words?

Comment: I haven't heard any common term here in the US Midwest.  I'm sure one will develop soon, however.

Comment: An accident waiting to happen?! Don

Comment: I've found [this photo](https://valentinagurarie.files.wordpress.com/2014/04/japan1.jpg?w=593&h=333) about using smartphones while walking  from Japan. It is clever. It says “Walking while using a smartphone is dangerous.”  Under the warning, in parenthesis,”But those people probably didn’t see this announcement.”

Comment: @ermanen. Really interesting picture though I've never seen it. As such, 'walking while using smartphone' is becoming a prevailing problem more than airpolution and littering.

Comment: *bumping into lamp posts* A not-so-long-ago phenomena among the British newspaper-reading public.

Comment: But apparently the expression is still used today :) http://blog.creamglobal.com/right_brain_left_brain/2009/05/how-to-avoid-bumping-into-lampposts-while-iphoning.html and here is a video of Johnny Lydon speaking about iPods http://www.nme.com/news/public-image-ltd/63337

Comment: (One does wonder, though, what it means to walk in English.  I always considered walking to be language-independent.  ;))

Comment: I call it "searching for a soulmate," since a person who does it is especially likely to run into someone else who's doing exactly the same thing.

Comment: I think this is one of those quirks of Japanese. They have lots of simple phrases describing specific situations for which there is no simple English equivalent.

Comment: @Mari-Lou. I think 'Bumping-into-post proof i-phone' is a great idea. I'm sure Japan where 80% of all i-phone users do reading / texting i-phone while walking, which is really annoying to me, a non-mobile phone user will be the most promissing market for this gadget in the world.

Comment: Honest, I once saw a guy looking at his cell phone while riding a motorbike. He went past before I could see what happened next but, good grief, Darwin award.

Comment: The moment when you realize you're interested in the answer that would describe yourself. / looking at this post while walking...

Comment: I usually say "cyberzombie."

Comment: Related: I once heard *of* the phrase ["blackberry jam"](www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Blackberry+Jam) whereby people walking slowly because they're on their (blackberry) smartphone cause traffic jams. I say "heard *of*" because I've never actually heard it used...

Comment: As an example, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bGpVpsaItpU

Comment: I don't know what the term for the action would be, but I call the people doing it "squishies", after the sound produced when you run one over with your car.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

There is the term ***smartphone zombie***.

> A smartphone zombie is a pedestrian who walks slowly and without attention to their surroundings because they are focussed upon their smartphone. ***[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smartphone_zombies)***

Technically, it is called ***[distracted walking](https://www.google.ca/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=distracted%20walking)***. I've seen *cellphone-distracted walking* as a more specific term also.

Another option is *text walking* and it looks like [Belgium has a solution](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/worldnews/europe/belgium/11674215/Antwerp-introduces-text-walking-lanes-for-pedestrians-using-mobile-phones.html) for it:

[image: "TEXT WALKING LANE" in middle of sidewalk]

*Image source: telegraph.co.uk*

---

I've also found the slang term ***petextrian*** while searching *distracted walking*. I've never seen it before but it is a clever coinage. And yet another slang term is ***wexter***.

Comment: To me, zombie is a small group of abnormal or insensitive persons. While 'aruki smaho' practice is becoming a prevailing custom or practice of smartphone users today. Eight out of 10 peoples are looking into smartphone while walking on street today in Japan. Is the word 'zombie' still applicable to bulk of today's smartphone users?

Comment: @YoichiOishi: *Smartphone zombie* is kind of a humorous coinage based on the behavior of fictional zombies. It is applicable to everyone who is walking and using their smartphones at the same time without paying attention to the environment.

Comment: A "zombie", in US horror movies, is commonly depicted as a person walking with arms outstretched in front, moving in a random direction without paying any attention to what's ahead.  Hence they often walk into things.  This is a pretty close match, image-wise, to the smartphone user walking while texting.  Hence the phrase.

Comment: A "text walking lane" a good idea, where the pavement is wide enough. I think that lane should have the occasional bollard or traffic sign, just to discourage the practice (and I'm sure some unthinking council employee will oblige anyway). But perhaps someone coming the other way will be enough.

Comment: Is that 'text walking lane' for real?  It looks like a really good practical joke to paint that text in cycle lanes...

Comment: @Jeremy -- In fact, it appears to have been photoshopped in.

Comment: The portmanteau _Smombie_ has even be elected the German(!) [Youth Word of the Year](http://www.thelocal.de/20151114/are-you-a-smombie-german-youth-word-2016).

Comment: Make petextrian the main answer and I'll upvote.

Comment: 'Petextrian' - cute coinage. I wish it could be adopted in OED and CED.

Comment: "Stupid" and "dangerous" come to mind

Comment: @Dubu: … and never been uttered by any young person, ever, in my experience.

Comment: This is more appropriate than you guess. There's a bad habit here involving them walking in front of trains.

Answer (score 10):

I've heard those to be called "walk and text" (also "text and walk"), which I believe is derived from the [walk and talk](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Walk_and_talk) trope.

[Scientific studies](http://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone) and [various](http://www.msn.com/en-us/news/connectedworld/study-humans-are-adapting-to-walk-and-text/ar-BBljzEq) [news](http://metro.co.uk/2015/06/20/todays-lesson-this-girl-demonstrates-why-you-shouldnt-text-while-walking-5255309/) [articles](http://www.tweentribune.com/article/teen/china-creates-sidewalk-people-who-walk-and-text/) used "walk and text" to refer to this behaviour. As well as an Android app called [Walk and Text](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.incorporateapps.walktext&hl=en) that claims to prevent bumping into something while in the middle of walking and texting.

Google search comparisons (double quotes used to prevent superfluous results):

- ["text and walk"](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=%22text+and+walk%22) - about 317,000 results
- ["walk and text"](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=%22walk+and+text%22) - about 153,000 results
- ["smartphone zombie"](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=%22smartphone+zombie%22) - about 63,100 results
- ["nomophobic" pedestrian](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=%22nomophobic%22+pedestrian) - about 665 results

Comment: Google is notoriously unreliable with their estimates, if you click on the link, you'll see that **"nomophobic" pedestrian** in actual fact has only [64 results](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=%22nomophobic%22+pedestrian#q=%22nomophobic%22+pedestrian&start=80) While ["nomophobic pedestrian"](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=%22nomophobic%22+pedestrian#q=%22nomophobic+pedestrian%22), in inverted commas, has only one result.

Comment: "text and walk" on the other hand seems stable at 315, 000 hits https://www.google.com.au/search?q=%22text+and+walk%22#q=%22text+and+walk%22&start=200

Answer (score 9):

Smartphone zombie is a good candidate. But if you don't like comparing living humans to zombies, you could consider using "***nomophobic pedestrians***".

"[***Nomophobia***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nomophobia)", which is a compound noun from "no + mobile + -phobia", means:

> ***the fear of being out of mobile phone contact***. It is,
>   however, arguable that the word "phobia" is misused and that in the
>   majority of cases it is only a normal anxiety ... According to Bianchi and Philips (2005) psychological factors are
>   involved in the ***overuse of a mobile phone***.

[Wikipedia]

There is a nomophobia-related [article](https://www.psychologytoday.com/blog/artificial-maturity/201409/nomophobia-rising-trend-in-students) that explains:

> Nomophobia is a term describing a growing fear in today’s world — ***the
>   fear of being without a mobile device***, or beyond mobile phone contact.

[Psychology Today]

We never know how "popular" words such as "nomophobia" or "nomophobic" will become, but nowadays people use them more often than before. You would need an additional explanation (or scare quotes) when using them.

You could also consider using "***phone-addicted pedestrians***".

"[Phone (or smartphone) addiction](https://www.psychologytoday.com/blog/reading-between-the-headlines/201307/smartphone-addiction)" is a broadly used term to describe "phone-separation anxiety".

Comment: "nomophobic" and "smartphone anxiety" seems to focus on the phone part, but not the walking part, nowhere does those words imply that they're doing it while walking.

Comment: To me, "nomophobic pedestrian" sounds like a smartphone addicted person who just happens to be walking on the street at that time. The term doesn't imply that they're using a phone **while** walking on the street. Likewise with "phone-addicted pedestrian".

Answer (score 6):

I've heard it called "dumbwalking", which I personally find apt and catchy.  Here is a [relevant BBC article](http://www.bbc.com/news/magazine-28208144).

Answer (score 4):

iPlodding

That's my word for it anyway :-)

As commented below, it references the "i" term used by Apple products. It also has all of the different forms...

- iPlodding (to iPlod) is the verb
- iPlodder is the person doing it
- etc...

Plus, everyone knows what you mean when you say it.

Comment: This is **the** answer, easy to say, single word, references existing 'i' usage, plodding is already known as a slow, inefficient walk. Even though Google only returns 2k hits, not all of which are for the whole word, this should be the canonical answer. I propose this community start a campaign, with a hashtag, to popularise this word and usage.

Answer (score 2):

**[Text-walker](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=text-walker)** has not been suggested yet:

> One who **text messages while walking**, mostly found on sidewalks.
> *That text-walker almost bumped into me!*

From [www.dailymail.co.uk](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/sciencetech/article-2573087/Text-AND-walk-App-makes-mobile-transparent-street-typing.html):

> SENDING MESSAGES ON THE GO AFFECTS BALANCE, SAY SCIENTISTS
>
> They also warned that **text-walkers** are at risk of wandering in front of traffic and stumbling onto train tracks – and urged pedestrians to stop before type.

Another option could be **[social zombie](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=social%20zombie&defid=7089830)**. It's a broader term for a person totally absorbed in their smartphones (and social media), wherever they are:

> No matter where they are or in what situation, the Social Zombie always has a **smartphone in front of them** and their head bent downwards **looking at the screen**.
>
> On the street: **Social Zombies** walk with head down, looking at smartphone, often get involved in a lethal car crash accident.

In addition, there's also **type and walk**:

> In China, there’s a special place for people who like to **type and walk**

([www.soyacincau.com](http://www.soyacincau.com/2014/09/14/in-china-theres-a-special-place-for-people-who-like-to-type-and-walk/))

Answer (score 1):

According to certain people, talking on the phone and walking is called *twalking*. As a website (*[The Joint](https://www.thejoint.com/illinois/wheaton/wheaton-21013/300946-do-you-know-what-twalking-is)*) explains,

> Twalking is the word used to describe those people who are looking down at their phones while walking. They may be texting, reading, selecting music, or playing a game, but whatever they are doing, it's enough to distract them from what they really should be doing, which is paying attention to their surroundings.

Comment: What do those people call talking on the phone while working?