# Is there a term for the people who walk around with their phones in their hand?

Tags: phrase-requests

Everyday I see them and probably you do too.  People, generally under thirty, walking with their phone in hand, quite often with no other visible burden, no wallet, no purse.  Presumably they're ready to instantly answer a call or a text or whatever.  Is there a term, preferably non-pejorative, for this behavior?

Comment: Maybe *millenials* ;)

Comment: We could say they are living a "hand-to-ear" existence.

Comment: Why non-pejorative. I'd love a pejorative one.

Comment: The Germans have come up with an amusing portmanteau, with English roots: smartphone + zombie = smombie. This, however, denotes a more totally absorbed relation with *das Handi* than OP perhaps has in mind..

Comment: I mean, my wallet generally isn't visible?

Comment: Digital native?

Comment: @Azor-Ahai Generally the people I see are wearing pants tight enough to know they're not carrying a wallet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Nomophobe** derived from "nomophobia"

> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nomophobia
>   "Nomophobia is the fear of being out of mobile phone contact".

**[phubber](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=phubber)** (urban-dictionary)

> The combination of the words, "phone" and "snubber" which means people who lower their heads looking at their smart phones.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phubbing

[Related question on stack exchange](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/287643/what-do-you-call-the-habit-of-looking-into-smartphone-while-walking)

Comment: The question doesn't seem to imply that the phone is being utilized, only that they're holding it.

Comment: @Catija Using is a subset of holding.

Comment: But if the OP is strictly looking for a word for someone who's **holding but not using** their phone, this doesn't apply.

Comment: @Catija  do you know anyone who holds a mobile phone all day long without checking whatsapp, selfies, texting, or whatever these people do. In order to use the cell phones they have to hold it. Unless they're driving...The OP says: *Presumably they're **ready to instantly answer a call** or a text or whatever*

Comment: I think "nomophobe" and "nomophobia" are the answer to my question although I'm glad to have added "smombie", "iPlod" and "phubber" to my vocabulary as well.